# How to find available resources in a Kubernetes Cluster level?

Tags: kubernetes

Do we have a simple command through which we can find the available resources at cluster level?

Available CPU and Memory requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is very useful script to monitor kubernetes resources

```
https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2019/monitoring-kubernetes-cluster-utilization-and-capacity-poor-mans-way
```

i would suggest to use prometheus to get such metrics

Answer (score 14):

There are couple of ways to achieve this. You didn't mention what environment are you using, however you probably already have [`metric server`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/resource-metrics-pipeline/#metrics-server) in your cluster.

**1. `Top` command**

`kubectl top pods` or `kubectl top nodes`. This way you will be able to check current usage of pods/nodes. You can also narrow it to `namespace`.

**2. Describe node**

If you will execute `kubectl describe node`, in output you will be able to see Capacity of that node and how much allocated resources left. Similar with `Pods`.

```
...
Capacity:
 attachable-volumes-gce-pd:  127
 cpu:                        1
 ephemeral-storage:          98868448Ki
 hugepages-2Mi:              0
 memory:                     3786684Ki
 pods:                       110
Allocatable:
 attachable-volumes-gce-pd:  127
 cpu:                        940m
 ephemeral-storage:          47093746742
 hugepages-2Mi:              0
 memory:                     2701244Ki
 pods:                       110
 ...
```

**3. Prometheus**

If you need more detailed information with statistics, I would recommend you to use [`Prometheus`](https://prometheus.io/). It will allow you to create statistics of nodes/pods, generate alerts and many more. It also might provide metrics not only CPU and Memory but also `custom.metrics` which can create statistics of all `Kubernetes` objects.

Many useful information can be found [here](https://www.replex.io/blog/kubernetes-in-production-the-ultimate-guide-to-monitoring-resource-metrics).

Comment: Just want to point out that describing `Allocatable` by "how much allocated resources left" might be misleading, as this does not refer to resources consumed by pod resource requests. I clarified the terms in my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be careful about the distinction between "allocatable" and "unallocated". Every node has certain amounts of resources for memory, CPU and ephemeral storage which are **allocatable**. From the [Kubernetes docs on allocatable resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/#node-allocatable):

> 'Allocatable' on a Kubernetes node is defined as the amount of compute resources that are available for pods. The scheduler does not over-subscribe 'Allocatable'.

And that's it. The field `.status.allocatable` of a node refers to resources that are available generally, **ignoring resources requested by pods** which are scheduled onto that node right now.

For a vanilla Kubernetes cluster without any metrics-server running (which is an optional component), if we want to know what resources on a given node are **unallocated right now**, we can use the data provided by "Allocated" field by running `kubectl describe node-name`. Example output:

```
(...)
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests   Limits
  --------           --------   ------
  cpu                75m (7%)   0 (0%)
  memory             50Mi (2%)  170Mi (9%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)     0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)     0 (0%)
(...)
```

To get the amount of unallocated resource, you do have to do the math of yourself, by subtracting allocated resources from allocatable resources.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try https://github.com/robscott/kube-capacity ?
it has a nice CLI for what you need. pay special attention to the first row (star) this is what you asked for.

```
$ kube-capacity
NODE            CPU REQUESTS    CPU LIMITS        MEMORY REQUESTS   MEMORY LIMITS
*               236888m (47%)   2595014m (518%)   457068Mi (53%)    1225718Mi (142%)
10.184.249.15   1690m (5%)      7400m (23%)       5691Mi (9%)       8218Mi (14%)
10.184.249.16   2805m (71%)     11400m (291%)     6873Mi (52%)      12314Mi (93%)
10.184.249.17   3827m (24%)     12626m (79%)      9140Mi (69%)      12326Mi (93%)
10.184.249.22   5093m (32%)     16403m (103%)     9403Mi (71%)      23586Mi (179%)
10.184.249.27   3805m (97%)     13400m (342%)     7897Mi (60%)      15386Mi (117%)
10.184.249.58   21567m (67%)    271848m (853%)    38922Mi (66%)     113074Mi (193%)
10.184.249.6    20038m (62%)    263452m (827%)    38246Mi (65%)     115507Mi (197%)
10.184.249.8    22123m (69%)    274492m (862%)    38547Mi (65%)     115766Mi (197%)
10.73.80.203    1690m (5%)      7400m (23%)       5691Mi (9%)       8218Mi (14%)
10.73.80.209    3700m (94%)     11400m (291%)     7759Mi (59%)      14362Mi (109%)
10.73.80.218    21984m (69%)    273956m (860%)    39035Mi (66%)     114884Mi (196%)
10.73.80.220    22262m (69%)    254028m (797%)    34644Mi (59%)     107426Mi (183%)
10.73.80.223    19482m (61%)    281808m (885%)    42036Mi (71%)     122037Mi (208%)
10.73.80.238    3293m (20%)     10903m (68%)      6991Mi (53%)      11746Mi (89%)
10.73.80.239    1800m (46%)     9400m (240%)      5839Mi (44%)      9242Mi (70%)
10.73.80.243    3698m (23%)     12603m (79%)      8715Mi (66%)      15306Mi (116%)
10.93.203.131   1690m (5%)      7400m (23%)       5691Mi (9%)       8218Mi (14%)
10.93.203.133   2713m (17%)     13103m (82%)      6693Mi (50%)      11922Mi (90%)
10.93.203.160   3700m (94%)     11400m (291%)     7759Mi (59%)      14362Mi (109%)
10.93.203.162   3700m (94%)     11400m (291%)     7759Mi (59%)      14362Mi (109%)
10.93.203.180   21011m (65%)    278804m (875%)    39823Mi (67%)     119195Mi (203%)
10.93.203.183   2500m (15%)     9400m (59%)       8032Mi (61%)      13114Mi (99%)
10.93.203.184   21289m (66%)    279276m (877%)    39767Mi (67%)     119025Mi (203%)
10.93.203.188   21428m (67%)    251712m (790%)    36126Mi (61%)     106127Mi (181%)
```